# How to convert ndarray::ArrayView to &ndarray::Array without copying?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, borrowing

I'm using the `ndarray` crate and I have a function that take a reference to `Array2`:

```
fn use_array(array: &Array2<u8>) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to call this function with a view:

```
image.axis_iter(Axis(2)).for_each(|layer| {
    fun(&layer.to_owned());
});
```

It leads to an error:

```
   |
92 |         fun(&layer);
   |             ^^^^^^ expected struct `ndarray::OwnedRepr`, found struct `ndarray::ViewRepr`
   |
error: could not compile `poisson-editing`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
   = note: expected type `&ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<u8>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
              found type `&ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::ViewRepr<&u8>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
```

I can solve it by owning the array elements, but then I'm creating an unnecessary copy of the array.

```
image.axis_iter(Axis(2)).for_each(|layer| {
    use_array(&layer.to_owned());
});
```

Is there a way to avoid the copy here?

---

Update:

Now I consider it a foolish question. This conversion is not possible because you can not have `&T` without creating `T`. There is clearly no way to create `Array2<u8>` without retaining ownership over the underlying data. I deluded myself into thinking that it should be possible because both `ArrayView` and `&Array` does not own the data.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't obtain an `&Array2<u8>`, because an `&Array2<u8>` is always a reference to a full 2d array, while your `layer` contains additional metadata to identify the correct sections of the owned `Array2` that are accessible.

However, you could do it the other way around: You can make `use_array` take an `ArrayView2<u8>` (if it's not part of some external code you depend on) and then change any calls that previously called `use_array` with a full 2d array reference to `use_array(your_array2.view())`.

Comment: Actually what I tried to achieve was to get "fake" `&Array2d<u8>` that references only the part of the original array that was pointed by the `ArrayView2<u8>`. It was quite foolish.